# RegEx to identify years from before 1000 AD to after 2000 AD

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a family tree web app and need to verify the input of the value for birth and death years.  These can be prefixed with '~', '>', or '<' signifying 'about', 'after' and 'before'.

```
'~1935' 
'>1820'
'<982'
```

The year itself can be from before 1000 AD to after 2000 AD, so can have either 3 or 4 digits. I need a RegEx to verify the user input.

I have tried, but am not familiar enough with regex to come up with the correct sequence. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[~><]?(\d{3,4})$
```

It looks for an optional `~`, `<` or `>` at the start of the string, followed by 3 or 4 digits, then the end of the string.

Sample usage:

```
$dates = array('~1935', '>1820', '<982', '2013', '3045', '123');
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if (preg_match('/^[~><]?(\d{3,4})$/', $date, $matches) && $matches[1] <= date('Y'))
        echo "$date is valid\n";
    else
        echo "$date is not valid\n";
}
```

Output:

```
~1935 is valid 
>1820 is valid 
<982 is valid 
2013 is valid 
3045 is not valid
123 is valid
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/thouG)

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  I just substituted '<= date("Y")' for the $matches[1] test and it works perfectly.

Comment: @JohnEmerson I wasn't sure if you would want that check so made it simple. Using `<= date('Y')` is definitely the way to go.